# Why I have 2 after second call?

Tags: python

```
class s:
    i = []

def inc():
    t = s()
    t.i.append(len(t.i))
    return len(t.i)


print(inc())
print(inc())
```

my output:

```
1
2
```

but I expected:

```
1
1
```

becouse everytime created new object, where my mistake?

Comment: There's no reason to downvote this question.  OP has code, and a legitimate, albeit incorrect understanding of the code.

Comment: @SteveP. I downvoted because (a) it's a misunderstanding which any half-decent tutorial that gets this far ought to dispel immediately; (b) we have probably hundreds of near-duplicates of this question already.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel We each have our own downvote preferences, but I understand your point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are appending to a variable of the *class*, not a variable of the *instance*

```
class s:
    i = []
```

This code creates a variable in the class. This is similar to the concept of a **static** variable in Java or C++.

In java:

```
class S {
    static List i = new ...
    }
```

You probably wanted to do this:

```
class s:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = []
```

This creates a variable in the *instance*, which is named self (similar to **this** in Java or C++). `__init__` is the constructor of the class.

Comment: One of those things you have to watch out for when writing Python - "if the variable doesn't exist it will create it". Is there a Python equivalent of VBA's `Option Explicit`? I realize that "declaring variables" is not a Pythonic Thing...

Comment: No, we have nothing like that, for better or worse.

Answer (score 3):

You should make i `instance` variable

```
class s:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = []
```

Answer (score 3):

You have made `i` a variable of the class itself.

If you want a variable for each class instance use `self`

```
class s:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = []
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify the instance variable:

```
class s:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = []

def inc():
    t = s()
    t.i.append(len(t.i))
    return len(t.i)
```

You are now modifying the same list of class `s` and hence it increments from 1 to 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try making i an instance variable.

```
class s:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = []
```